# Change incoming call pop-up setting programmatically

Tags: java, android, settings

What I am trying to do is change the setting named "Incoming call pop-up" programmatically from the app (perhaps in the `Application` class).

The setting can be found in `Settings -> Phone -> Call Settings`.

Please see attached screenshot:

[image: Incoming call pop-up setting]

I know there are ways to change settings from within an app, but I just can't find how to change this one.

Comment: "The setting can be found in Settings -> Phone -> Call Settings" -- on this device, perhaps. It is not a general Android setting. For example, it does not exist on the Nexus 5X running Android 6.0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this is not a general Android setting, but I would still appreciate any help in changing this setting programatically in phones where it exists. Is this impossible?

Comment: You would have to contact your device manufacturer and ask them whether or not it is possible. Beyond that, you would need to buy one of every Android device ever manufactured (or the subset that you care about), determine which ones of those have this setting (or some equivalent), and then contact *those* device manufacturers, asking the same question.

Comment: So it **is** possible! thanks! :)